# Duplicate elements created during jaxb marshalling

Tags: java, jaxb

While marshalling using JAXB, duplicate elements are getting created in the output. Following is my root class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="rules")
public class RuleList {

    @XmlElement(name="rule")
    private List<Rule> ruleList;

    public List<Rule> getRules() {
        return ruleList;
    }

    public void setRules(List<Rule> ruleList) {
        this.ruleList = ruleList;
    }

}
```

This creates duplicates entries. For e.g if I have 2 entries in the list it creates 4 entries in the output xml.

Comment: please share the `Rule` class

Answer (score 0):

The getRules(..) method of the RuleList was duplicating the records.
Changing it to only rules() i.e. removing the **get** solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following annotation to your class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

Otherwise your JAXB implementation will see both the getter/setter pair as well as the annotated field and assume that your class has two properties, and will use them both.

(You can also add this annotation to the package that contains your domain model classes, by putting it in a `package-info.java` file in the package - then you don't have to add it to each of your classes).